# Data Migration from MySQL to GreenPum using PXF

Tags: mysql, jvm, greenplum

Need advise on configuring **pxf** threads and JVM memory.
I'm trying to load a 300 GB table from a MySQL database into **Greenplum**(Open Source) server which has all its segments on a single host with a total available memory of 62 GB. Can't adopt a data division strategy due to its nature (i mean need to load 300 GB data at once).

How can I apply auto-commit on **pxf** threads or advise any other strategy?

System Configuration is as below:

8 GP segments with 62 GB physical RAM and 8 GB Swap

Comment: PXF will only open a connection per Greenplum segment, but that is if you enable `PARTITION_BY` http://greenplum.docs.pivotal.io/pxf/5-15/using/jdbc_pxf.html. With `PARTITION_BY` you can specify a column on MySQL where you can partition your data. This will speed up your transfers. I wrote a blog about it here: https://engineering.pivotal.io/post/pxf_speeding_up_jdbc_reads/

Comment: Unfortunately the table size is quite big and we can't create PARTITION now. Is there any other workaround through which we can migrate a single table of size 300 GB in single go using PXF.

Comment: How it should be if we limit the maxThreads of PXF from 200 to 20

Comment: The default of 200 should be fine for your use case. As for memory the defaults will work for you if you are running on a single thread.

Comment: Can you share your version of Greenplum and PXF version? With fairly recent versions of PXF, the default settings will work for your use case.

Comment: I was running GP cluster on single host but it got fail because of JVM, GP version is 6.8 and PXF is 5.11

Comment: Can you share the error details?

Comment: Due to chocking of JVM PXF gets stop and we face below error:

SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: remote component error (0) from '127.0.0.1:5888':Empty reply from server (libchurl.c.935) (seg20 slice1 *.*.*.*:50020 pid=29432) (libchurl.c.935)
Where: External table ext_sales_expansion

Comment: I am looking for the log files located under `$PXF_CONF/logs/*`

Answer (score 0):

What's the Greenplum version?
A modified version of mysql_fdw(https://github.com/adam8157/mysql_fdw_greenplum) for Greenplum 6 can connect to mysql from master. It doesn't need JVM.
However, you would need to build the extension by yourself.

Comment: While following FDW facing below error, using provided link

[gpadmin@DBTestVm02-Arch mysql_fdw-2.0.1]$ which pg_config
/usr/local/greenplum-db/bin/pg_config
[gpadmin@DBTestVm02-Arch mysql_fdw-2.0.1]$ export PATH=/usr/local/greenplum-db/bin/:$PATH
[gpadmin@DBTestVm02-Arch mysql_fdw-2.0.1]$ make USE_PGXS=1
Makefile:35: *** PostgreSQL 9.3, 9.4 or 9.5 is required to compile this extension.  Stop.

While my GP version is 6.8 and psql version is 9.4.24

Comment: Looks strange because 9.4.24 should satisfy the required PostgresSQL version. I haven't tested it but it looks like it should work according to those link: https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpdb/issues/7916, https://www.jianshu.com/p/d0f93c14ed42

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the late reply, but it took some time to look into this issue.

I believe the root cause of the issue is that PXF uses a connection pool to access data on the external database system. By default, The [maximum number of actual connections to the database backend](https://github.com/greenplum-db/pxf/blob/master/server/pxf-service/src/templates/user/templates/jdbc-site.xml#L36) is 5. That means that, in your case, 3 out of 8 segments will wait for up to 30 seconds ([default timeout](https://github.com/greenplum-db/pxf/blob/master/server/pxf-service/src/templates/user/templates/jdbc-site.xml#L42)) to obtain a connection from the pool, after the 30 seconds the query will fail. I believe that is what's causing the error in your case.

My suggestion is for you to increase the `jdbc.pool.property.maximumPoolSize` value to 10. If you have concurrent requests, then you would need to multiple that number times the number of concurrent requests. Alternatively, you can disable connection pooling for your use case by setting the `jdbc.pool.enabled` property to false.

Please review the documentation for more information [about JDBC connection pooling](https://greenplum.docs.pivotal.io/pxf/5-15/using/jdbc_cfg.html#jdbcconpool) in PXF.